# using angular service on ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function UserService($http) {
        var service = {};

        service.GetAll = GetAll;
        service.GetById = GetById;
        service.GetByUsername = GetByUsername;
        service.Create = Create;
        service.Update = Update;
        service.Delete = Delete;

        return service;
```

How can I write this service on ionic framework in services.js. can I use exactly the same or should I change something in syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can name it anything as you have service.js but it is in angular term a factory.

An angular service has syntax like

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
```

And to answer your question **yes** you can use it just have to close the opening brackets in the above syntax

```
(function () {
   'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('UserService', UserService);

UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
function UserService($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.GetAll = GetAll;
    service.GetById = GetById;
    service.GetByUsername = GetByUsername;
    service.Create = Create;
    service.Update = Update;
    service.Delete = Delete;

    return service;
   }
})
```

hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Just one more question. can I put all the services in one js file. for example I created services.js in /www/js path.

Comment: Yes, you can. but it is **not** recommended, inside the js folder make a new directory named say `services` and make one js file for each service by this it is much cleaner, easier to debug, and manageable. :)

Comment: yess :) that seems more proper. however if I create another directory named "services" inside js folder, should I have to declare a path for these services in somewhere or can system recognize it automatically?

Comment: You jusr have to change their path in index.html if previous it was js/services.js so now it would be js/services/serviceOne.js ..